# How to use functions in the command window of Dymola?

Tags: modelica, dymola

I am working with Dymola, and try to use the functions provided by Modelica standard library in the command window, but it seems that I can't use them, and I couldn't claim a variable of a specific type either. I am wondering if there is some kind of limit of the command I could use in the command window of Dymola. Where should I find all the allowable commands?

[image]

I try to use some functions from Modelica.Media, it seems the input variables are out of range, but I tried a lot of times and different units system. I find that I can't declare a variable of pressure type in the command window, but `Modelica.Media.Water.IF97_Utilities.h_pT()` requires that I need to provide the variable as `pressure` and `enthalpy` type, is this the reason I can't use this function in the command window?

```
Modelica.Media.Water.IF97_Utilities.h_pT(1e6,800,1)
Failed to expand Modelica.Media.Water.IF97_Utilities.h_props_pT(
  1000000.0, 
  800, 
  Modelica.Media.Common.IF97BaseTwoPhase(
    phase = 1, 
    region = 1, 
    p = 1000000.0, 
    T = 800.0, 
    h = 9.577648835649013E+20, 
    R = 461.526, 
    cp = 1.8074392528071426E+20, 
    cv = -3.7247229288028774E+18, 
    rho = 5.195917767496603E-13, 
    s = 1.2052984524009106E+18, 
    pt = 645518.9415389205, 
    pd = 6.693617079374418E+18, 
    vt = 357209983199.2206, 
    vp = -553368.7088215105, 
    x = 0.0, 
    dpT = 645518.9415389205
  )).
Failed to expand Modelica.Media.Water.IF97_Utilities.h_pT(1000000.0, 800, 1).
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: To declare variables, you have to leave away the type. Simply use `p=12`.

Comment: Functions can usually be used like you show. Maybe someone with more knowledge about the Media package knows why it does not work with the Utility functions in the Media package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the inputs are valid there seems to be an issue specifically related to evaluating some media-functions interactively in Dymola (since they shouldn't be evaluated in models). It will be corrected in Dymola 2022x.

A temporary work-around is to first set the flag `Advanced.SemiLinear = false;` and then:

```
Modelica.Media.Water.IF97_Utilities.h_pT(1e6,800,1)
 = 9.577648835649013E+20
```

(I'm not sure how valid the formulation is in that region.)

But please remember to set `Advanced.SemiLinear = true;` before translating and simulating any models - in particular models using media-functions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are giving the function an invalid input. It seems Dymola does not give you the error-message for this based on the screenshot and logs you provided. I tried it in OpenModelica and got:

```
Modelica.Media.Water.IF97_Utilities.h_pT(100e5, 500e3)
[Modelica 4.0.0/Media/Water/IF97_Utilities.mo:2245:9-2246:77] Error: assert triggered: IF97 medium function g5: input temperature (= 500000 K) is higher than limit of 2273.15K in region 5
```

By using a value within the limits, it returns a value:

```
Modelica.Media.Water.IF97_Utilities.h_pT(100e5, 1e3)
```